# Como verificar se uma variavel recebeu um valor novo em python?

Tags: mysql, python, thread

tenho uma Thread de uma função que insere dados no banco e outra Thread que a cada segundo recebe um valor novo para uma variavel, contudo pode ser  o mesmo valor anterior só que "novo".
Queria saber como faço para a thread esperar esse  valor novo e toda vez que receber  esse  valor  novo fazer o insert no banco.
Uma parte do meu codigo  :

```
def EnviaBanco():
    global nomepessoa  # nomepessoa é uma variavel global em outra função, esse nomepessoa esta  dentro de um  while que  esta recebendo um novo valor  a  todo momento
    global cam
    Conectando banco de dados
    try:
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
          host="localhost",
          user="teste",
          password="teste102030",
          database="teste"
        )
        print ("Conexão realizada com sucesso")
    except:
        print("[ERROR] verifique a conexão com banco  de dados")
    
    while True:
    " if nomeatual recebeu um novo valor: "
        time.sleep(10.0)
        #Inicializando banco
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        #Inserindo dados
        sql = ("INSERT INTO teste (nomes, camera) VALUES (%s,%s)")
        #Executando os dados  e comitando
        mycursor.execute(sql,(nomepessoa, cam))
        mydb.commit()
        print("Dados inseridos com sucesso")
'''
```

Comment: A lógica da sua função está um pouco estranha. Criar um cursor dentro do loop não é uma boa prática. Evite usar `global`. Vou responder abaixo de uma forma genérica, pois não sei como você pega o dado.

Comment: **1)** Por que ter uma thread só para fazer a inserção? **2)** Se realmente necessário, leia sobre a estrutura de dados fila (*queue*).

Answer (score 0):

De uma forma genérica faça algo como:

```
class ConexaoBanco():
   _instance = None
   def __init__(self):
       pass

   @staticmethod
   def get_instance():
       if ConexaoBanco._instance == None:
          ConexaoBanco._instance = ConexaoBanco()
       return ConexaoBanco._instance

    def conecta(self):
        # conecta no banco
        self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                                            host="localhost",
                                            user="teste", 
                                            password="teste102030",
                                            database="teste"
                                          )
        self.mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()

    def getCursor(self):
        return self.myCursor()

    def close(self):
        self.mycursor.close()
         self.mydb.close()


def processaNome():
    # Pega cursor
    mydb = ConexaoDB().get_instance()
    mycursor = mydb.getCursor()
    #
    lastNome = None
    while True:
        # Pega o nome
        nomePessoa = ... # aqui o processo de pegar o nome.
        if nomePessoa != lastNome:
            sql = ("INSERT INTO teste (nomes, camera) VALUES (%s,%s)")
            mycursor.execute(sql, (nomePessoa, cam))
            lastNome = nomePessoa
        time.sleep(10)
```

Nota: a classe ConexaoBanco pode ser melhorada. Mas o importante é a forma de manter o último nome pego.

Ainda, acredito que você não precise cada uma delas, ou seja pegar nome e inserir no banco, em uma *thread* diferente.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu pra da uma  ideia de como posso  fazer no meu codigo, agradeço

Answer (score -1):

Há o módulo queue e a classe Queue que permite fazer isso de forma segura.

Comunicação entre threads é tecnicamente complicada, não tente criar seu próprio esquema do zero.

Aliás, se puder evitar usar threads, use processos com um pipe entre eles. Vale até usar uma conexão TCP/IP local entre dois processos para que fiquem mais bem isolados.